# How can I mantain the spacing on contructing string by checking the values of an object

Tags: javascript

Return a string that replace the character to it's respected value in the string,
if the character does not exist, add '?' into your result string.
Rememeber to maintain spaces in between.

My problem is that I cant create spaces in my result string. Is something wrong with my conditional statements?

```
var dict = {a: 'e',
            s: 'o',
            b: 't',
            g: 'q'
           };

function second(str, obj) {
  let result = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (obj[str[i]] === undefined) {
      result += '?';
    }
    else if (obj[str[i]]!== undefined && str[i] !== ' ') {
      result += obj[str[i]];
    } else if (obj[str[i]] !== undefined && str[i] === ' ') {
      result += ' ';
    }     
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(second('hi bro what is going on', dict)); // '?? t?? ??e? ?o q???q ??'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `if (obj[str[i]] === undefined) {` check - the space does not exist in the object, so it concatenates a `?`.

You can add a space to the dict to fix it:

```js
var dict = {a: 'e',
            s: 'o',
            b: 't',
            g: 'q',
            ' ': ' '
           };

function second(str, obj) {
  let result = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (obj[str[i]] === undefined) {
      result += '?';
    } else result += obj[str[i]];;
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(second('hi bro what is going on', dict)); // '?? t?? ??e? ?o q???q ??'
```

Or, if you can't modify the dict:

```js
var dict = {a: 'e',
            s: 'o',
            b: 't',
            g: 'q'
           };

function second(str, obj) {
  let result = '';
  for (const char of str) {
    if (char === ' ') result += ' ';
    else if (obj[char]) result += obj[char];
    else result += '?';
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(second('hi bro what is going on', dict)); // '?? t?? ??e? ?o q???q ??'
```

Or use a regular expression to match word characters:

```js
var dict = {a: 'e',
            s: 'o',
            b: 't',
            g: 'q'
           };

const second = (str, obj) => str.replace(
  /\w/g,
  char => dict[char] ?? '?'
);

console.log(second('hi bro what is going on', dict)); // '?? t?? ??e? ?o q???q ??'
```

Comment: I *was* going to add that you could also check if it's a space - you edited it to add that too, though. Maybe for other characters you want to preserve, make a `preserve` dict and check if any characters are in there as well?

I mean, this seems like homework or something so I don't think that's necessary, but it could prove useful for... something else (IDK what this would be good for, anyways).

Comment: the nullish operator is quite new as of now, I would recommend using something else for support.